# Raphael.js How to remove click handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events, raphael

If I have append a click event handler function to my Raphael element like this:

```
var paper = Raphael("mycanvas", '100%', '100%');


var clickHandler = function(){
     //DO SOME THING
}

var myRect = paper.rect(140, 10, 30, 30);
myRect.click(clickHandler);
```

How to remove this click handler later?

I tried `myRect.click()`, I suppose it will empty my click handler function, and will remove my previous click handler for `myRect`, but it does not.

So, How to remove this click handler later?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try
    myRect.unclick(clickHandler);